# Sampling uniformly from n-sphere using spherical coordinates

Tags: sampling

It has been explained [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpherePointPicking.html) why sampling from [n-sphere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere) is not achievable with naive parametrization. And it explains how to correct it for 3 dimensions. Can somebody please guide me what is the correct method for uniformly sampling in n dimensions using the spherical coordinates? i.e.
\begin{align}
&x_1 = r \cos(\phi_1) \,\\
&x_2 = r \sin(\phi_1) \cos(\phi_2) \,\\
&x_3 = r \sin(\phi_1) \sin(\phi_2) \cos(\phi_3) \,\\
&{}\,\,\,\vdots\\
&x_{n-1} = r \sin(\phi_1) \cdots \sin(\phi_{n-2}) \cos(\phi_{n-1}) \,\\
&x_n = r \sin(\phi_1) \cdots \sin(\phi_{n-2}) \sin(\phi_{n-1}) \,.
\end{align}

Comment: Why do you want to do this via spherical coordinates instead of the more conventional way, as mentioned in your second link?

Comment: @cardinal Because actually I am not after sampling now(I will use it later when I need Monte Carlo methods). Right now I am dealing with the case of parametrization of a $n-1$-sphere to be able to assign probability to points on it. A uniform sampling method  based on this parametrisation will provide me with one way to do so, right?

Comment: The hypersphere is my parameter space.

Comment: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HyperspherePointPicking.html