# Draw n-dimensional uniform sample from a unit (n-1)-sphere defined by (n-1)-dimensional variable

Tags: sampling, optimization

So my question is same as [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/77440/sampling-uniformly-from-n-sphere-using-spherical-coordinates) and [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/103090/injective-uniform-distribution-on-an-n-sphere) which were not answered.

I will explain why do I need this. Perhaps, there could also be a different solution. I use a black box gradient-free optimizer (Bayesian Optimization for clarity) of some cost function $f(x)$, where $x \in R^n$. A special property of the function is that $f(x) = f(ax)$ for any scalar $ a>0$, so the relative scale of $x$ does not matter. Therefore, I add a constraint $||x||_2=1$ which well-poses the search problem.

Possible options are:

1) Black box optimizers usually avoid such constraints. But it is possible to add a regularizer like $(||x||_2-1)^2$ to the cost function. However, I think it is possible to avoid it using the third option.

2) Normalize all elements of $x$ as $x \gets x / ||x||_2$. The inverse mapping is one-to-many, which means that BO will waste time sampling $ax, a>0$ vectors, if for some $a$ we already know $f(ax)$.
For the same reason, [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Generating_random_points) is not applicable in my case.

3) Reduce BO sampling dimension by 1, that is to sample $(n-1)$-dimensional variables, which on a unit (n-1)-sphere map into $n$-dimensional Cartesian vector. I am trying to figure out how to do it, but cannot find any way of doing it.

Comment: Do you mean this map in $n$ dimensions? $[0, 2\pi) \mapsto \text{unit circle in $\mathbb{R}^2$}, f(\phi) = (\cos(\phi), \sin(\phi))$? I.e. sample in $[0, 2\pi)$ uniformly and then transfer this onto the unit circle?

Comment: Yes, but in $n=8$ dimensions in my case

Comment: Well, then the first link provides an answer: Sample $\phi_1, ..., \phi_{n-1}$ independently and uniformly in $[0, 2\pi)$ and then transfer them to the sphere using the map given in the first link with $r=1$...

Comment: The solution for the two-sphere given at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7977/how-to-generate-uniformly-distributed-points-on-the-surface-of-the-3-d-unit-sphe/7984#7984 generalizes in the obvious way to any number of dimensions.

Comment: Fabian, then points on the sphere are not uniform anymore https://corysimon.github.io/articles/uniformdistn-on-sphere/

Comment: @Ivan oh yes, you are right... it depends on the measure and the pushed measure is not the 'natural one' one needs in this case...

Comment: whuber, do you mean normalization? but then I map $n$-dim points into $n$-dim points which is in my case is exactly same in terms of cost function evaluation, since normalization does not change anything.

Comment: @Xi'an, I looked at you suggestion 2 days ago and I look now, and I still can not make sense out of it. Can you maybe send me a link which may provide some theoretical background behind this method, so I could hopefully understand it?

Comment: @Ivan, did my answer make sense? As you can see, there is no theory involved. Your question remains somewhat unclear as to which type of sampling you would consider acceptable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using spherical coordinates, 
\begin{align*}
x_1 &= \cos(\phi_1)\,,\\
x_2 &= \sin(\phi_1)\cos(\phi_2)\,,\\
&\quad\quad\vdots\\
x_{n-1} &= \sin(\phi_1)\cdots\sin(\phi_{n-2})\cos(\phi_{n-1})\,,\\
x_n&=\sin(\phi_1)\cdots\sin(\phi_{n-2})\sin(\phi_{n-1})\,,\\
\end{align*}
the $n$-dimensional unit sphere is parameterised by $(n-1)$ angles, $\phi_1,\ldots,\phi_{n-2}\in(0,\pi)$ and $\phi_{n-1}\in(0,2\pi)$. The uniform distribution on that sphere is associated with the joint density
$$\sin(\phi_1)^{n-2}\sin(\phi_2)^{n-3}\cdots\sin(\phi_{n-2})$$
which means that the $\phi_i$'s are independent with respective densities
$$\sin(\phi_1)^{n-2}\,,\ \sin(\phi_2)^{n-3}\,,\ldots,\ \sin(\phi_{n-2})$$and the Uniform $U(0,2\pi)$ on $\phi_{n-1}$. Simulating directly the $\phi_i$'s according to these densities thus returns the proper distribution of the angles for a uniform on the sphere, from which the Euclidean coordinates can be derived.

[image]

Simulating the $\phi_i$'s can be done (rather inefficiently) by accept-reject when using $\pi_1(\phi)\propto\sin(\phi)$ as a proposal since
$$\sin(\phi)^d \le \sin(\phi)\qquad d\ge 1\qquad \phi\in(0,\pi)$$as illustrated by the following picture (representing $\sin^d$ for $d=1,2,\cdots,5$ and simulations from $\pi_1$ accepted or rejected depending on the target:

[image]

There exists however a more efficient way to simulate from the densities $\sin(\phi)^d$. Indeed, if$$\phi\sim\pi_d(\phi)\propto\sin(\phi)^d$$then, by a change of variable$$X=\cos(\phi)\sim f_d(x)\propto (1-x^2)^{(d-1)/2}\mathbb{I}_{(-1,1)}(x)$$and$$Y=X^2\sim g_d(y)\propto (1-y)^{(d-1)/2}y^{-1/2}\mathbb{I}_{(0,1)}(x)$$meaning$$Y\sim\mathcal{B}e(1/2,(d+1)/2)$$Therefore simulating $\phi$ from $\pi_d$ amounts to

1. generate $Y\sim\mathcal{B}e(1/2,(d+1)/2)$ and $S=1-2\mathbb{I}_{U<1/2}$ for $U\sim\mathcal{U}(0,1)$
2. take $\phi=\cos^{-1}(S*\sqrt{Y})$

As shown by the picture below for $d=3$, the fit on $10^5$ simulations is correct, as expected:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for detailed explanation. Now I see how you derived it. It answers the question nicely! However, I was not clear enough about the question, and now I see that the title is wrong, as well as point 3) in my question. Maybe I should make another question for this. But in short: Bayesian Optimization gives me a $n-1$-dimensional point $x \in [a,b]^{n-1}$ which I want to map to a $n$-point which lies on a unit sphere.